# Jquery find with multiple matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm using Jquery to find the users email in my site, but I don't know how can I find a email for users with the same name.

Using this code, my variable return just one value for string.

```
var mail = $("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('" + name + "')" ).siblings("td").eq(1).text();
```

How can I get all strings that match in this `find` event?

Thanks!

EDIT: My code don't have any HTML markup for data, I'm using Google Spreadsheet to get the values.

Imagine there is one table with:

```
<tr><td>Name 1</td><td>mail1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name 2</td><td>mail2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name 1</td><td>mail3</td></tr>
```

If I use `find` containing "Name 1", my variable should return `mail1, mail3`.

Comment: can you add some html example?, its imposible to help you without knowing the structure.

Comment: show html markup where those user names are shown

Comment: I'm using a Google Spreadsheet to get the values

Comment: `.siblings("td:nth-child(2)").map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get()`

Comment: Edit the post. adeneo, this code return a null value. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure works for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/86mjcffs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the second column of all matching rows, use `nth-child`.
To get all values in an array, you can use `map()` and `get()`

```js
var name = 'Name 1';

var mail = $("#dat").contents()
                    .find("td:contains('" + name + "')" )
                    .siblings("td:nth-child(2)")
                    .map(function() { 
                     return $(this).text(); 
                    }).get()

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mail, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dat">
    <tr><td>Name 1</td><td>mail1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name 2</td><td>mail2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name 1</td><td>mail3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The query for find could be more specific as well, that way using `siblings` wouldn't be neccessary

```
var mail = $("#dat").contents()
                    .find("tr:has(td:contains('" + name + "')) td:nth-child(2)" )
                    .map(function() { 
                        return $(this).text(); 
                    }).get()
```

Comment: Can you just explain the 0 , 4 inside JSON.stringify?

Comment: @ZecaNovaes - That line just outputs the result to the body so you can see what's going on when clicking the *"run snippet"* button, and isn't really important, but the 0 and 4 are just arguments to the `strinigfy()` function, where `0` is the "replacer", a function that replaces, where I pass `0` as it's not being used, and then the `4` is the number of spaces to use when formatting the JSON representation of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should change you code a little, to:

```
mail = $("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('" + name + "')" ).next().text();
```

Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vwjsdmfa/)

Comment: I can't remove eq(1). I get the values in a Google Spreadsheet, and eq(1) return the value of one column. I need to repeat this function and get the value (if matched) in the same column in other row.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay, I'm trying to remove eq(1), but my spreadsheet have more than just two columns, I need the value in the second column only, and Google don't allow me to edit the HTML to add some different class for every column